# Navigate to the last frame from SwapChainBackgroundPanel

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps, directx-11

I am writing a Windows Store app using C++/XAML with DirectX interop - SwapChainBackgroundPanel.

The application is based on the template "Split Page". From each list view item, a DirectX page may be launched using code below.

```
Window::Current->Content = ref new MyD3Components::DirectXPage();
Window::Current->Activate();
```

This is working fine and DirectX page opens up and plays very well.

What I would like to have a button in the app bar which helps user to go back and display the "Split Page" to allow selecting another DirectX page. This I have not been able to accomplish yet.

Among several things I have tried, below is the most logical one to my opinion. It gives a "Platform::DisconnectedException" when user wants to go back to the last page.

```
Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Frame^ rootFrame = SDL::App::GetRootFrame();

Window::Current->Content = rootFrame;
Window::Current->Activate();
```

Please look to see if you have a suggestion or better a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error, I am in the position to answer my own question. It seems that all I needed to do was to remove my rendering callbackfrom the CompositionTarget.

It was added like below.

```
m_eventToken = CompositionTarget::Rendering::add(ref new Windows::Foundation::EventHandler<Object^>(this, &DirectXPage::OnRendering));
```

Before replacing the current window and activating it, I called below.

```
CompositionTarget::Rendering::remove(m_eventToken);
```

I guessed this helped DirectX not to output to rendering pipeline and complain (disconnectedexception) when the target is not there.

Answer (score 1):

Here the sample example for your question :

What i am creating : 2 pages...
You will have (go to page 2)link on page 1...If u click that,the second page should appear that says "Page 2" at the top. Notice that there is a back button to the left of the page title. Click the button to return to the first page...

1.) Find the TextBlock element named pageTitle and change the Text property to Page 1. The    XAML should look like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Grid.Column="1" Text="Page 1" 
       Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
```

2.)Add the following XAML as a second child element to the root Grid. The StackPanel element should be a sibling to the Grid that contains the back button and page title.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="120,0,120,60">
 <HyperlinkButton Content="Click to go to page 2" Click="HyperlinkButton_Click_1"/>
</StackPanel>
```

3.)Make the following changes to BasicPage2.xaml.
Find the TextBlock element named pageTitle and change the Text property to Page 2. The XAML should look like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Grid.Column="1" Text="Page 2" 
       Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
```

4.)Add the following XAML as a second child element to the root Grid. The StackPanel element should be a sibling to the Grid that contains the back button and page title.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
    Margin="120,0,120,60">
  <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="tb1" Text="Hello World!"/>
</StackPanel>
```

5.)Add the following code to the BasicPage1 class in BasicPage1.Xaml.cs

```
private void HyperlinkButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BasicPage2));
}
```

6.)Now that we've prepared the new pages, we need to make BasicPage1 the first thing that appears when the app starts. Open app.xaml.cs and change the OnLaunched method to call Frame.Navigate by using BasicPage1 instead of the BlankPage. The entire OnLaunched method should look like the following:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
// Create a Frame to act navigation context and navigate to the first page
var rootFrame = new Frame();
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(BasicPage1));

// Place the frame in the current window and ensure that it is active
Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

Now you are ready to test the app. Start the app, and click the link that says Click to go to page 2. The second page should appear that says "Page 2" at the top. Notice that there is a back button to the left of the page title. Click the button to return to the first page.
Thats it! hope it helps u.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it does not address my question. In my case, DirectX interop, SwapChainBackgroundPanel, is involved and I think this is the source of problems.